# Android SearchView Formatting

Tags: android, searchview, spannablestring

Spent far too long on this problem now. Have solved most of it, but still struggling with the search hint icon. Having searched extensively this following bit of code does work in my fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    int id = mSearchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    mSearchViewTextView = (TextView) mSearchView.findViewById(id);
    mSearchViewTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    mSearchViewTextView.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    mSearchViewTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.action_textfield_search_alpha);

    mSearchViewSsb = new SpannableStringBuilder("   ");
    mSearchViewSsb.append(getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_friend_add_search_hint));
    Drawable searchHintIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(MyApplication.getContext(), R.drawable.action_search);
    int textSize = (int) (mSearchViewTextView.getTextSize() * 1.25);
    searchHintIcon.setBounds(0, 0, textSize, textSize);
    mSearchViewSsb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(searchHintIcon), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    mSearchViewTextView.setText(mSearchViewSsb);

    int id1 = android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn;
    ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(id1);
    searchCloseIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_close);

    int id2 = android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button;
    ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(id2);
    searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_search);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, getActivity().getMenuInflater());

    mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(...);

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(...);

}
```

However, it only works once when I call it in onCreateOptionsMenu. I have tried to reuse it in setOnQueryTextListener, but no matter what I do the application then either crashes or just ignores the change.

Also, when it is set once the curious thing is that the first time you have to press the cancel button twice, the first time you press the cancel button the SearchView TextView has all of the enhancements but the SearchHint Icon goes back to its original form.

All I need is that SearchHint icon to be white.

My theme is set to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make the icon white you can add the following code to your menu file

```
   <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
```

Comment: I already had pretty much this aside from two things. I don't use collapseActionView and I was using android.widget.SearchView. I wasn't using the support libraries as our minimum SDK, due to some other dependancies, was 21. I may investigate using the support library version if I get time.

Comment: you can use support library even in the minimum sdk version is 21, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Tried it, does exactly the same thing, so this answer doesn't work for me. Sorry Umang.

Comment: probably you are not inflating the correct menu layout in onCreateOptionsMenu() and you need to initialize the SearchManager in onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the whole code block. I don't think its that simple, but I am willing to admit its likely to be something I have done.

Comment: you are missing out the most important line getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu); where menu_main is your menu file name

Comment: Its in the super class, which is why I call super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, getActivity().getMenuInflater());

Comment: if you look at code of onCreateOptionsMenu http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-0/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29. Moreover each developer can have a different name for the layout file, hence you need to do it explictly

Comment: Just realised I hadn't specified this is a fragment, note the void in public void onCreateOptionsMenu(...)

Comment: really? you have change the signature the method defined in super class. Not sure what you are trying to do